# 'service call phone' codes

Tags: android, tasker

### Overview:

Hello all,

I am trying to automate the side door to my apartment with tasker on my phone.

### Attempt:

Here is what I have:

- Android: 5.1.1
- Kernel: 3.10.61
- SM-G920V (Verizon Galaxy S6) (unrooted :-/)

[image] [image: Unable to do this the traditional way do I am trying to CLI this] [image]

### Issue:

The only problem with this is that it appears that `service call phone 6` ends the call rather than automatically answering it.

### Questions:

- It also appears that `service call phone` codes are not easy to find and are prone to change between android releases. Is there a good source of information that I can refer to like a `man` page or something?
- Is there a better way to do this without root access?

### Edit:

I should also point out that `Test` is a contact saved in my phone for my google voice number (unlinked to my phone number) and that when I receive a call from my google voice tasker turns green for the duration of the call (visible after I removed `service call phone 6` event from task chain):

[image]

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`service call`

try

`input keyevent 5`